# Synonyms for "big deal"

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, synonyms

I have read on [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/big+deal) that the expression *big deal* may be used as an interjection to answer ironically *"to indicate that something is unimportant or unimpressive"*. If it is the case, what else expressions could be used in this meaning?

Answer (score 1):

> so what

I would say this is the canonical phrase.

Also:

> *And...?*

(the ellipses indicating a pause before the question mark)